¿Cómo puedo hacer un loop para obtener bases de datos en R con las siguientes especifícaciones?
¿Cómo puedo realizar un loop en R que me permita cargar una serie de bases de datos que van desde 1997 hasta el 2022 (considerando solo los meses de Marzo, Junio y Septiembre con nombres similares tipo: MesAño.dta)? Considerando la Encuesta de Marzo como correspondiente al primer trimestre, la de Junio como la del segundo, la de Septiembre como la del tercero y la de Diciembre como la del cuarto y último trimestre del año. La idea es que se puedan combinar verticalmente todas las bases de datos en un solo objeto, en donde pueda identificar cada fila con el trimestre-año desde donde se obtiene. Para lo que sigue, y considerando solamente las siguiente variables: ident, orden, numper, pcoh, sexo, edad, horas, ingfam, ingtrab, arriendo, sitocup2, arrienm y sitocup1.

Deberías de estructurar mejor la pregunta y aportar algo de código de base para que podamos ayudarte a corregirlo ;)
